# How to use paratheses inside a Javascript string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a function for creating images from an array and I need to put some extensive HTML inside a javascript string. Unfortunately whenever I use parentheses, it throws off the whole thing.

Any help?

This:

```
listItem.innerHTML = "<img src='" + listData[i] + "'>"; */
```

This doesn't:

```
listItem.innerHTML = "<div class='item square' style='background-image: url(" + listData[i] + ")'></div>";
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/QKuLk/ You need to show a complete example that demonstrates the problem. What does "throws off the whole thing" mean? Does the div have a height so that you can see the background? Does the URL contain spaces or special characters?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q2j5N/

Answer (score 3):

Your code depends on `listData[i]` being valid when tossed into three places:

- CSS’s `url()`
- CSS
- HTML

It shouldn’t. Building HTML in JavaScript isn’t a very good idea in the first place. If you truly have enough markup that *must* be built dynamically that you can’t use the DOM, use a template engine that knows its target. In this and most cases, use the DOM!

```
var itemImage = document.createElement('div');
itemImage.className = 'item square';
itemImage.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + encodeURI(listData[i]) + '")';
listItem.appendChild(itemImage);
```

This creates one element, assigns values to some of its properties, and appends it to `listItem`, and it will always do that; you don’t have to hope that your quotes matched up properly or that you remembered to escape absolutely everything.

Footnote: the combination of `encodeURI` and double quotes around the `url()` value will almost certainly fix any potential problem – quotes or parentheses – regardless of which method you use to add them, but that doesn’t mean you should keep using `innerHTML`.